# How to get an instance of IServiceProvider

Tags: c#

Currently my code works in dependency injection. It uses `IServiceProvider` and creates an instance of my secret manager. Then uses that to create dbcontext that's scoped. I would like to change this slightly as it's making a call to aws everytime a new instance of dbcontext is created.

My current code

```
public AppBindings(HostBuilderContext ctx, IServiceCollection services) : base(ctx, services)
{
}

public override void AddBindings()
{
    Services
        .AddScoped<IDbContext>(x =>
        {
            return new DbContext(x.GetService<ISecretManager>().Get("TestApi"));
        });
}
```

My goal is to store `x.GetService<ISecretManager>().Get("TestApi")` into a variable and pass that into DbContext instead of the code being inside of it. Something like this

```
public override void AddBindings()
{
    var connection = _serviceProvider.GetService<ISecretManager>().Get("TestApi");
    Services
        .AddScoped<IDbContext>(x =>
        {
            return new DbContext(connection);
        });
}
```

May I ask how can I access `IServiceProvider` here.

Comment: Did you try that exact code?  It should work.  You can store it in a member variable to keep it around.  Just check for null before you create it.

Comment: Not quite sure how do I do that as I don't have an instance of serviceProvider.  


builder.Host.ConfigureServices((ctx,services)=>
    new AppBindings(ctx,services).AddBindings()); @TimRoberts

Comment: Beats me, that's not the question you asked.  You asked how to store your `"TestApi"` instance into a variable so you didn't have to create it each time.  I don't  see `IServiceProvider` in this code.  Perhaps the question you asked is not really the one you need answered.

Comment: My post literally says May I ask how can I access IServiceProvider here. And read the title. Goal vs question are two different things. The answered question helps achieve the goal. @TimRoberts